# SQL if last day of pervious month has value change the beginning date of next month to start from that day

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help with this sql code, I would like to roll back start day of new month if last day of pervious month has values.

Thanks

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Lastly, don't post any images as they cant be cut and pasted.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest nesting EOMONTH() in an IF statement.

Not sure what table(s) you're working with, but general layout would be:
IF(MAX(date_column) = EOMONTH(MAX(date_column), MAX(date_column), new_date)

Reference for EOMONTH():
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-date-functions/sql-server-eomonth-function/